# Hitting connection limits with Azure functions and Azure SQL (node.js)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, tedious

I have a function app that serves a node.js API. We are hitting the 900 concurrent connections limit with tedious connected to Azure SQL and realize we should add connection pools (unless there is a better recommendation of course).

[Azure Functions + Azure SQL + Node.js and connection pooling between requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234272/azure-functions-azure-sql-node-js-and-connection-pooling-between-requests) seems to answer our prayers but wanted to validate how you can use a single connection pool with Azure functions

Is the best practice to put "let pool = new ConnectionPool(poolConfig, connectionConfig);" above mode.exports on all functions? Is that not creating a new pool every time an individual function is called?

Microsoft doesn't have clear documentation on this for node.js unfortunately so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the whole Function app share one single pool, we need to put the initialization part to a shared module. Christiaan Westerbeek had posted a [wonderful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30356582/9191057) using [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql), there's not so much difference between a Function app and a web app in this respect.

I recommend using `mssql`(use `tedious` and `generic-pool` internally) instead of [tedious-connection-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious-connection-pool) which seems not updated for 2 years.

Put the connection code in `poolConfig.js` under a `SharedLib` folder.

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const config = {
    pool:{
        max:50 // default: 10
    },
    user: '',
    password: '',
    server: '', 
    database: '',
    options: {
        encrypt: true // For Azure Sql 
    }
};
const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
    console.log('Connected to MSSQL');
    return pool;
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err));

module.exports = {
  sql, poolPromise
}
```

And load the module to connect to sql. We use await to get ConnectionPool the function should be async(default for v2 js function).

```
const { poolPromise } = require('../SharedLib/poolConfig');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    var pool = await poolPromise;
    var result =  await pool.request().query("");
    ...
}
```

Note that if Function app is scaled out with multiple instances, new pool will be created for each instance as well.